# Calculate normal distribution probability in php

Tags: php, probability, distribution, normal-distribution

I need to use this table to get the probability from a given z value:

https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/img/normal-table-large.png

I'm sure there should be a better way to get those values on php but don't know how to calculate them.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you.**

Comment: I'm sorry. It's not because I'm lazy but because I lack enough mathematical knowledge to solve it. Just wondering if someone has faced this problem before me as it seems quite usefull for general statistical purpouses. Sorry!

Comment: Have you considered feeding data into `R` via `PHP` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table, I believe, is CDF of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). I coded it using expression for
[error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) approximation.

Code is untested!

```
function sgn( $x ) {
  if ( $x < 0 )
    return -1;
  return 1;
}

function erf( $x ) {
  $e  = exp(-$x*$x);
  $e2 = exp(-$x*$x*2);

  $q = sqrt(pi())/2 + 31*$e/200 - 341*$e2/8000;

  return 2*sgn($x)*sqrt(1-$e)*$q/sqrt(pi());
}

function CDF( $x ) {
    return (1 + erf($x / sqrt(2))) / 2;
}

print_r(CDF(0));
print_r(CDF(0.1));
....
```

UPDATE

Here is quick (untested!) code to compute erf() with up to 4 terms

```
function erf( $x ) {
  $e = exp(-$x*$x);
  $t = 1.0 - $e;

  $s = 1. + $t*(-1./12. + $t*(-7./480. + $t*( -5./896. +$t * (-787./276480.))));

  return 2.*sgn($x)*sqrt($t)*$s/sqrt(pi());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. I have just test it and I think the result is quite accurate although the values are not exactly the same.

Comment: @LuisHP glad to hear. Values are not the same is because I used simple only two terms approximation (Burmann series) for `erf()` function. You could take a look at Wikipedia article on `erf()` and expand approximation up to 4 terms, which should improve the result. If you happy with the answer, please accept it

Answer (score 4):

A quick approximation to the standard normal distribution's CDF (Сumulative distribution function) can be found by using a Taylor series approximation:

[image]

So, this is my PHP implementation of CDF:

```
function cumulativeNormalDensity($x, $mean = 0, $stddev = 1, $precision = 256) {
  $result = 0;
  $x -= $mean;
  $x /= $stddev;
  for ($i = 0, $k = 1; $i < $precision; $i++) {
    $n = $i * 2 + 1;
    $k *= $n;
    $p = pow($x, $n) / $k;
    if (is_nan($p) || is_infinite($p)) break;
    $result += $p;
  }
  $result *= 1 / sqrt(2 * pi()) * exp(-pow($x, 2) / 2);
  $result += 0.5;
  return max(0, $result);
}
```

Comment: should be ```$stddev``` instead of ```$dev``` at the 4th line. :)

Comment: Fixed! Thank you very much @"Pak Ho Cheung"!